# what's wrong with DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].Values

Tags: datakey

I am using datalist to show some data.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlT" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsT"  DataKeyField="TID,TTypeID" onitemdatabound="dlT_ItemDataBound" >
```

in code bahin, I need datakey value:

```
protected void dlT_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                string Tid = dlT.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].Values["TID"].ToString();
                      ...
        }
```

I always to get error "**'object' does not contain a definition for 'Values' and no extension method 'Values' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**" Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataList doesn't allow you to specify multiple keys, So it's different from gridview